# Finding points in a plane

Tags: graphics3d, trigonometry

The end of the Star Wars saga is near, so I feel compelled to design a [Mouse Droid](https://www.starwars.com/databank/mouse-droid).  Based upon the [Paul Murphy's schematics](http://luckyxero.com/droids/mouse-droid-build/) I've reconstructed the outline of the top shell:

[image]

Since my goal is to create a 3D-printable object, I'd like to carve out the inside of the shell, and this objective has tested the limits of my trigonometry knowledge.

**The goal** is to create an identical shape (excluding the brim) that is scaled to provide an arbitrary thickness in the x,y,z directions (in practice, the x and y thicknesses will be identical and typically thinner than the z thickness).  Because the object will be 3D printed, *thickness* must be defined in the [x,y,z] dimensions, so the approach I'm using is to assign the z thickness, find points in a new plan that intersect with the shell outline, and translate as appropriate in the x and y directions to get the coordinates for the cutout.  I'm stuck here:

```
pts = {{1.53685, 1, 0.6}, {2.77444, 2.81657, 7.6187}, {15.5486, 2.81657, 
  7.6187}, {20.4632, 1, 0.6}, {1.53685, 11.25, 0.6}, {2.77444, 
  9.43343, 7.6187}, {15.5486, 9.43343, 7.6187}, {20.4632, 11.25, 
  0.6}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 12.25, 0}, {22, 12.25, 0}, {22, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0.6}, {0, 12.25, 0.6}, {22, 12.25, 0.6}, {22, 0, 0.6}};
pl1 = pts[[{0, 4, 7, 3} + 1]];
pl2 = pts[[{1, 5, 6, 2} + 1]];
Graphics3D[{
  Red, Thick, MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {pl1, pl2}],
  Red, Opacity[0.1], Polygon[pl1],
  Blue, Opacity[0.1], Polygon[pl2],
  Black, Polygon[# + {0, 0, 5.6187} & /@ pl1]
  }, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "What is the point on red line that intersects black plane?"]
```

[image]

Given the 8 points on two parallel planes and a third parallel plane of some known distance (2 units in this case) from the top plane, how to I find the four points where the red lines intersect the black plane?  The internal angles of the Mouse Droid are 80 and 55 degrees around x and 75 degrees around y.

Comment: Just by the way, have you checked out `ShellRegion`?

Comment: @CarlLange I was not aware of that function and it may be useful in the future.  At the moment, I am using MMA for the math but then move to a different program for CAD design that generates STLs that work nicely with my 3D Printer.

Comment: Yes, I've also found that that's the best workflow for my own 3D printing projects. Mathematica for the first 90% and then Blender or openSCAD for the second 90% 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lines = MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {pl1, pl2}];
plane = Polygon[# + {0, 0, 5.6187} & /@ pl1];
intersections = (RegionIntersection[plane, #] & /@ lines)[[All, 1, 1]];

Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, lines, Opacity[0.1], Polygon[pl1], 
  Blue, Polygon[pl2], Black, plane, Green, Polygon@intersections, 
  Opacity[1], Sphere[#, .3] & /@ intersections}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach to find the intersections:

```
scale = Rescale[.6 + 5.6187, MinMax[{pl1[[1, -1]], pl2[[1, -1]]}], {0, 1}];
intersections2 = pl1 + scale (pl2 - pl1) ;

intersections2 == intersections
```

> True

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, lines, Opacity[.1],  Blue, Hexahedron[pts], 
  Black, plane, Green, Polygon@intersections2, Opacity[1], 
  Sphere[#, .2] & /@ intersections2}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** A purely graphical approach using `ParametricPlot3D` (as in Cesareo's answer) with `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` options to find the desired intersections:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[pl1 + λ (pl2 - pl1), {λ, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{.06 + 5.6187}},
   MeshStyle -> ({Green, Sphere[#, .2] & @@ #} &)],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Red, Polygon[pl1], Blue, Polygon[pl2], Black, plane}], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the very Mathematica approach of the first answer, although I suspect the 2nd is going to be more useful as it can be more easily translated into something that works with my CAD software (openSCAD).

Answer (score 3):

If the planes defined by **pl1**, **pl2** are parallel then with the following procedure, we can construct parallel intermediate planes for each **lambda** value.

```
gr1 = Table[ParametricPlot3D[pl1[[k]] + lambda (pl2[[k]] - pl1[[k]]), {lambda, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], {k, 1,4}];
gr2 = Table[Graphics3D[Polygon[{pl1[[1]] + lambda (pl2[[1]] - pl1[[1]]), pl1[[2]] + lambda (pl2[[2]] - pl1[[2]]), pl1[[3]] + lambda (pl2[[3]] - pl1[[3]]), pl1[[4]] + lambda (pl2[[4]] - pl1[[4]])}]], {lambda, 0, 1, 0.2}];
Show[gr1, gr2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

NOTE

Given a plane defined by three points like

```
pts = {{2.15565, 1.90829, 4.10935}, {2.15565, 10.3417, 4.10935}, {18.0059, 10.3417, 4.10935}};
```

and a segment

```
seg = {{1.53685, 1, 0.6}, {2.77444, 2.81657, 7.6187}};
```

the intersection point is calculated as **pint** the solution **lambda** for

```
sol = NSolve[(seg[[1]]+lambda(seg[[2]]-seg[[1]])-pts[[3]]).Cross[pts[[1]]-pts[[3]],pts[[2]]-pts[[3]]] == 0,lambda][[1]]
If[0 <= (lambda /. sol) <= 1, pint = seg[[1]] + lambda (seg[[2]] - seg[[1]]) /. sol, Print["No intersection"]]

If[0 <= (lambda /. sol) <= 1,
    gr1 = ParametricPlot3D[seg[[1]] + lambda (seg[[2]] - seg[[1]]),{lambda, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
    gr2 = Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[pint, 0.1]}];
    gr3 = Graphics3D[Polygon[pts]];
    Show[gr1, gr2, gr3, PlotRange -> {{pint[[1]] - 2, pint[[1]] + 2}, {pint[[2]] - 2, pint[[2]] + 2}, {pint[[3]] - 2, pint[[3]] + 2}}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: An interesting approach; how does one extract the desired points where the lines intersect a given plane?

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm recording my approach to this problem to (a) have a repository for when I inevitably forget how to do this and (b) to avoid muddying up the question which others have provided helpful answers to.*

Here's my somewhat ugly approach having learned that knowing the length (via `Norm`) and direction (via `Normalize`) of the edges, I can construct a parallel edge with a shorter length that can be readily translated in the x and y directions.

```
th = {1, .5, 2};
dir = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}};
pl1 = pts[[{0, 4, 7, 3} + 1]];
pl2 = pts[[{1, 5, 6, 2} + 1]];
tr[pt_, th_, d_] := Module[{v = Last@pt - First@pt, u},
   u = (1 - th[[3]]/v[[3]]) Norm@v Normalize@v;
   u = # + {d[[1]], d[[2]], 0} th & /@ {First@pt, u + First@pt}
   ];
Graphics3D[{Thick,
  Red, MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {pl1, pl2}],
  {Opacity[0.1], Polygon[pl1], Polygon[pl2]},
  Blue, MapThread[Line[tr[{#1, #2}, th, #3]] &, {pl1, pl2, dir}]
  }]
```

[image]

`Hexagon` was new to me, which makes drawing the shell and cutout regions fairly straightforward.  `RegionDifference` works like a charm on these shapes.

```
cutout = Region@
  Hexahedron@
   Flatten[MapThread[tr[{#1, #2}, th, #3] &, {pl1, pl2, dir}], {2, 1}]
shell = Region[Hexahedron[pts[[1 ;; 8]]]]
RegionDifference[shell, cutout]
```

[image]